# How to make gallery full width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, gallery

I'm trying to make an image gallery full-width at whatever resolution.

Strangely, it's only when I click on the maximize button button on the browser window, the gallery goes full screen. So far I haven't been able to figure out the issue.

Here's the demo link ~

http://constantcontrast.com/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Find `boxlayout.js`, open it up and locate lines `54-57`. It should look something like:

```
if( !$section.data( 'open' ) ) {
    $section.data( 'open', true ).addClass( 'bl-expand bl-expand-top' );
    $el.addClass( 'bl-expand-item' );   
}
```

At the end of that, add:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $( window ).trigger( 'resize' );
    },
    500
);
```

So it should look like:

```
if( !$section.data( 'open' ) ) {
    $section.data( 'open', true ).addClass( 'bl-expand bl-expand-top' );
    $el.addClass( 'bl-expand-item' );   
}
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $( window ).trigger( 'resize' );
    },
    500
);
```